# Помогите составить регулярное выражения для функции preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка пути url вида '/testapi/moscow/user/123436566/messsage'.

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью функции php preg_match получить 'moscow' (может меняться на любой другой город)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи регулярки и preg_match это можно сделать так:

```
$matches = [];
$url = '/testapi/moscow/user/123436566/messsage';
preg_match('@/testapi/([^/]+)/user@', $url, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Но можно разбить строку по символу `/` и взять второй сегмент:

```
$segments = explode('/', $url);
echo $segments[2];
```

Оба варианта в [песочнице](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/85040).